# QVector2D and QVector3D value limitation

Tags: c++, qt

When I tried to use QVector2D or QVector3D, I got a strange value:

```cpp
QVector3D p2(858727.182, 40591545264.7, 0);

qDebug() <<  QString::number(p2.x(),'g', 12);
```

Output:

> "858727.1875"
> "40591544320"

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will address the fact that `858727.182` "*became*" `858727.1875`, and while not sure the following explanation is accurate, it will at least give you an idea about "***why?***".

First, [QVector3D::x()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvector3d.html#x) returns a float.

Second, here are 2 tests using `std::cout` and `std::setprecision`:

```
std::cout<< std::setprecision(12) <<(float)858727.182<<std::endl;
std::cout<< std::setprecision(12) <<(double)858727.182<<std::endl;
```

And their outputs:

```
858727.1875
858727.182
```

Third, here's an IEEE 754 Floating Point conversion using [IEEE-754 Floating Point Converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html):

```
Value: 858727.182
Value actually stored in float : 858727.1875
Binary : 0 10010010 10100011010011001110011
Error due to conversion: 0.0055
```

What you're observing is the result of [IEEE 754 standard of a binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

Same goes for [QVector3D::y()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvector3d.html#y), both numbers are too large for a `float` to store their exact values.

For more:

- [Why is the data stored in a Float datatype considered to be an approximate value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372670/why-is-the-data-stored-in-a-float-datatype-considered-to-be-an-approximate-value)
- [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)
- [Float value not being stored correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093227/float-value-not-being-stored-correctly)
- [Qt Forum: Type Conversion : from QString to float and double](https://forum.qt.io/topic/134869/type-conversion-from-qstring-to-float-and-double/3)
- [GFG: Why floating-point values do not represent exact value](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-floating-point-values-do-not-represent-exact-value/)